# How to update props dependent state

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, react-lifecycle-hooks

I have component connected to redux store which gets data from props:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({rowData: dataSelector(state)})
```

The component has its own state:

```
this.state = {
  rowsPerPage: 23,
  pageCount: 0,
}
```

I need to calculate new `state.pageCount` when `props.rowData` changes. How can i do it?

Comment: *'... when `props.rowData` changes'* can you explain in a bit more details what exactly changes your component's props? if it causes re-render somehow, you may use second (optional) parameter of [`mapStateToProps()`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#connect-extracting-data-with-mapstatetoprops), which is your component's `ownProps`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov, props.rowData i get with selector. Every time when i change filter option i extract new props.rowData and when i get new value i need to update state.pageCount

Comment: I'm guessing there's a slight mix-up in the way you pass your data back and forth. Would you share wider code context of your component wrapping up this feature?

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t show the code, besides, I don’t see any mix-up, the data flow from the redux-storage to the component is direct: components gets props and calculates new  state on it.

Comment: Nonetheless many thanks for the support!

Comment: You're most welcome, however, based on your initial comment, I'm still pretty sure there's something suboptimal in the way you pass state variables and props back and forth and, most probably, you could avoid certain complexities which you compound even further with your current path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206085/discussion-between---and-yevgen-gorbunkov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` to determine when the `props.rowData` changes by using an if condition. Based on when the value is changed, you can update your `state.pageCount` like the way you want.

Comment: How can i use prevProps in getDerivedStateFromProps?

Comment: `this.props` will give the previous props but the first argument of the method `getDerivedStateFromProps` will give the new updating props.

Comment: I can't use 'this.props',  getting error: "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined"

Comment: Try using `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

Please create componentWillReceiveProps

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
if(newProps.rowData.length !== this.state.pageCount) {this.setState({pageCount: newProps.rowData.length})}
}
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops).

Comment: Do you use React hooks? (React v > 16.8?)

Comment: The use of hooks is kind of irrelevant. Unless the question specifies, you should assume they are using a recent version. I'm not saying your answer won't work, I'm just pointing out and recommending that proposed solutions shouldn't use deprecated methods.

Comment: you can use UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: *Can*, but **should not**. Direct from the react docs regarding this method: "These methods are considered legacy and you should avoid them in new code". The point isn't that it won't work, its that you should not use it.